# Twig check for undefined in frontend

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to create an opened/closed shop widget in Twig. This have to be done in the frontend since I don't have access to create backend functions (SaaS platform)

I got almost everything working except for one thing. When you fill in a value that's not equal to one of the statements then the server throws a `500 internal error`. Whatever I try I just can't see how to check if that particulary var is set.

To clarify:

I can set these options:

```
theme.monday
theme.tuesday
theme.wednesday
etc...
```

Let's say I fill `theme.monday` with value `09.00-16.00`. Which means shop is open from 9am till 4pm. This works with below code. 
When I fill `theme.monday` with value `CLosED` then the code below works as well.

However when I fill `theme.monday` with value `Hello! blabla` then the server throws an internal error.

With my limited Twig knowledge I understand that this error comes from the var `combine`. If something else is set as value then that split function won't work offcourse.

My question is how to handle this? So how can I make some sort of check that will work when `theme.monday` is filled with something different then `closed` or `09.00-16.00`?

```
{% set open = false %}
{% set now = 'now' | date('U') %} 
{% set today = 'now' | date('l') | lower %}
{% set closedval = attribute(theme, today) | lower | t  %} 

{% if 'closed' in closedval %}
  {% set open = false %}
{% else %}
  {% set combine = attribute(theme, today) | split('-') %}
  {% set opening_time = combine[0] | date('U') %}
  {% set closing_time = combine[1] | date('U')  %}
  {% if (now < closing_time) and (now > opening_time) %}
    {% set open = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Things I tried are:

```
{% set open = false %}
{% set now = 'now' | date('U') %} 
{% set today = 'now' | date('l') | lower %}
{% set closedval = attribute(theme, today) | lower | t  %} 

{% set combine = attribute(theme, today) | split('-') %}

{% if 'closed' in closedval %}
  {% set open = false %}
{% elseif combine is not null %} 
{# or 
  {% elseif combine is defined %}
  {% elseif combine is not sameas(false) %}
 #}

  {% set opening_time = combine[0] | date('U') %}
  {% set closing_time = combine[1] | date('U')  %}
  {% if (now < closing_time) and (now > opening_time) %}
    {% set open = true %}
  {% endif %}

{% else %}
  {% set open = false %}
{% endif %}
```

However above won't work. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this something that should happen inside the view to begin with? I’d say your controller should rather perform that logic, and then just pass a value to the view that tells it whether the shop’s currently open or not …

Comment: Your question's title is incorrect/misleading. Surely the error you are receiving is something in the line of `Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Hello! blabla)`. Instead of trying to solve this in `twig` u'd better make sure that the input u save in the database is sanitised.

Comment: @DarkBee: Forgot to mention that this have to be done in the frontend. I don't have access to the backend since this is done on a SaaS platform. I've edited my post

Comment: You have access to custom twig `filters` / `functions`?

Comment: @DarkBee: Sadly only to standard Twig functions as mentioned in the Twig docs :(

Comment: You can't catch exceptions with vanilla twig though